# Xcode 11: Safe Area code implementation using Objective-C not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode11, safearealayoutguide

I am new to iOS application development and I am currently working on an existing iOS application written using Objective-C. I came across a requirement where I need to implement Safe Area programmatically. So I have implemented the following piece of code in "viewDidLoad" method.

```
if(@available(iOS 11, *)){
    UILayoutGuide * guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    [self.view.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
}else{
    UILayoutGuide * margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide;
    [self.view.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:margins.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:margins.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

But, when I try to run the application connecting to iPhone XR iOS Simulator device, the above code is not working. The view is not getting started after the safe area in landscape mode instead it is getting started from the safe area itself due to which the text is getting cut off

Am I missing anything? Can you please suggest on what needs to be done so that the safe area can be implemented?

Comment: try applying the constraint in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: In your code, there's no text's constraints. Please add it.

Comment: Earlier i tried setting constraints to the UILabel but the label width is getting increased due to which the controls are getting moved from the display area. Only the label contents are getting displayed in the entire screen. So i have applied the constraint to the view.

Answer (score 0):

What UI element are you trying to layout in your view? You mention text is getting cut off. The code you provided is setting the anchor from the view to *itself* and **not to the UI element**. Update your code to set the anchors of the UI element to the view.

```
UITextField *textField; // Your text UI element
UILayoutGuide * guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
[textField.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[textField.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
[textField.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor].active = YES;
[textField.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
```

Comment: Yes i have tried setting the anchors to the UI Element also but the UI element size is getting increased automatically such that it gets fits to the screen and moving the other contents (Which are present after the UIElement) to right such that they are not displayed on the screen. How the width of the UIElement for which the anchor is set can be controlled ?

Comment: Based on your anchors, I would expect the textField to completely fill the view. The width can be set using `widthAnchor` but then you won't need either the leading or trailing anchor. I'd recommend you review tutorials on auto layout basics.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use

```
constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfterAnchor: multiplier:
```

and

```
constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelowAnchor: multiplier:
```

instead of

```
constraintEqualToAnchor:
```

Also I'd recommend you to try setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO manually:

```
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

The full code:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];

textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:textField];

if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
    UILayoutGuide * guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;

    [textField.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfterAnchor:guide.leadingAnchor
                                                            multiplier:1.0].active = YES;

    [textField.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfterAnchor:guide.trailingAnchor
                                                             multiplier:-1.0].active = YES;

    [textField.topAnchor constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelowAnchor:guide.topAnchor
                                                        multiplier:1.0].active = YES;

    [textField.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelowAnchor:guide.bottomAnchor
                                                           multiplier:1.0].active = YES;
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this case earlier but it is of no use .The UI element size is getting increased automatically such that it is moving the other contents away from the screen residing beside it . Width of the label is getting increased when trying to set theseconstraints.

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample project where the issue reproduces? So I will be able to debug it and try to find the problem cause.